# Run 100+ SSIS packages in parallel from a parent package

Tags: ssis, package, parallel-processing

I have 100+ child packages and I need to run them in **parallel** from a parent package. For this I will have to create 100+ Execute Package tasks and then 100+ File Connections. This doesn't look appealing to me and it is repetative and error prone. Is there any other way to do this. Keep two things in mind.

1. Child package Execution should be in parallel (so no For loop and stuffs)
2. I am using **CheckPoint** based restart-ability and hence need control flow items at compile time (no script component based solutions too)

---

UPDATE: Even if you have massive hardware, windows limits the number of concurrent tasks you can start simultaneously due to an inherent design issue. Though I achieved parallel execution using jobs, I had to limit it to 25 parallel packages at a time to avoid random failures due to the windows issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up. There is no way AFAIK. I decided to create 100+ jobs, one job per package and using the same schedule. Creating jobs was easier using Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be file connections? Have you looked at the options of having the packages stored in the SSIS package store and referencing it from there.

You would still have your 100+ components, but not your 100+ file connections.

Comment: Thats true. But I am looking for packages stored in File System :(

Answer (score 0):

You could create the package dynamically with EzAPI.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api.aspx